# How to access a element that is loaded after a click event using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

The problem is that I'm trying to fill in a form for login. For the form to appear, I need first to click on a "sign in" button that I already clicked, then it shows me the form. But when I use

```
email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='emailAddress']")
```

to access the email input, it returns me the following error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='emailAddress']"}
```

I already tried to change the xpath, to use a *time.sleep* for wait the input to load, and nothing solved the problem.

site: nike.com.br
code:

```
def login(driver, username, password):    try:    LOGGER.info("Requesting page: " + NIKE_HOME_URL)    driver.get(NIKE_HOME_URL)    except TimeoutException:        wait_until_visible(driver=driver, xpath="//a[@id='anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2']")    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='anchor-acessar-unite-oauth2']").click()        wait_until_visible(driver=driver, xpath="//input[@name='emailAddress']")    email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='emailAddress']")    email_input.clear()    email_input.send_keys(username)
```

Comment: Post your code and the website

Comment: I edited the question with the code

Comment: is there an iframe on the page?

Comment: Yeah, there is one